# How to store data in a tree structure in R?

Tags: r, tree

I am building a decision tree. Now, I want to store splitting condition or threshold value, parent, leaf and other variable in a tree structure, so that I can call that again and get those values in time of prediction? I am not using any random-forest package as I want to get my tree as like I wish.

Comment: See partykit. In the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partykit/vignettes/partykit.pdf) there is an example how to build the tree manually.

Answer (score 1):

The list structure is the only way to go. Take a look at how the dendrogram objects are stored.

```
?as.dendrogram
```

The other package to review would be `igraph`.

Comment: Is list truly the only way? I think environment structure can be another way?

Comment: An environment is just a large list-like object (accessed with "[[" and "$") and can of course contain items of various classes, including other lists.

Comment: `rpart` uses a data frame and a matrix to store the tree and split structure.

Comment: I do know that is true, although technically a dataframe is also list. I admit that my use of "only" was intended as emphasis rather than a true logical expression.

Comment: How can I use rpart for storing values in each time of splitting?

Comment: This question makes very little sense to me. You should spend some time building with code an example of the data you expect, and any code you have attempted in solution of the problem and be sure to specify in detail the results you want.